# Raspberry Pi as a Wireless Wake-On-Lan Server

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I've got my Pi setup already for home automation for a few things, but I'd like to automate the startup my media center computer. My plan is to use the WiFi adapter I have on my pi to receive a command from the internet to send a Wake-On-LAN command over a direct Ethernet connection to the computer. My assumption is I would need to setup a bridge of some kind, but I do not know where to start really making the bridge in the command-line.

Comment: If by "command" you mean some process that will respond and react by sending the WOL, then it's more a matter of configuring a route.  My reading of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_lan#Magic_packet)  is that you don't actually have to do so -- you could send such a packet over the internet to the pi and forward it without change (depending on whether it really needs to be a broadcast or not).  I would strongly encourage you to pursue the details of this on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Actually it's probably just a matter of NAT'ing it to broadcast, if that's allowed.  Almost certainly this can be done one way or another w/ iptables and for that you should ask on U&L.

Comment: What system is currently running on your RPi? Raspbian or some other appliance kit?

Comment: Currently the RPi is running Raspbian with a samba server containing ripped DVDs for my media center and some GPIO scripts.

I would not like to open up the wake on lan port to the internet because I already have SSH forwarded. My plan is to send the packet with etherwake from the RPi. The issue is more of getting the computer to become a client and being able to be woken.

Comment: I'm going to close this because it's not an issue specific to the pi and you will be much better off asking on (our big sibling) [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  You need to add a route to the other computer via the ethernet NIC, and NAT the address to 255.255.255.255.  For the former, see `man ip route`, the latter is done with `iptables` (the kernel firewall interface).  The complication is whether or not that broadcast will be applied to the extra route.  It is not hard to experiment with since it is only a matter of a few commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Wake On LAN command with a mac address and a router that accepts the packets. There are multiple wol packages, they do require root though

Comment: That's not the problem. I know how basic Wake On Lan works. The issue is that my computer is not connected via ethernet to the router. So, I'd like to set my always on and wirelessly connected RPi on top it, and run an ethernet cable from the RPi to the computer. Over that ethernet cable, I'd like a Wake On Lan packet sent.

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Wake-on-LAN-Any-Computer-Over-Wireless-Network/